# Adding two 2D boolean arrays in java together

Tags: java

I have two 2D boolean arrays. Can I just "add" them together without looping over them? So the end result would be as follows: A cell that was false in both arrays remains false whereas if a cell contains true in any of the two arrays - the corresponding cell in the result array is true.

So for example...

**true false**

**false false**

added to...

**false true**

**true false**

would give

**true true**

**true false**

Comment: Loop on the arrays. What's wrong about that?

Comment: Its a large array, and there's many of them. If there was a simple way to just add them, that would be nice. Because they are all the same size

Answer (score 3):

No, but you could use Java's `BitSet` class to simulate a 2D boolean array and then combine two such bitsets using the `or` method, which would achieve what you want. See here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#or%28java.util.BitSet%29

In order to make it work for 2D, you need to map the indices appropriately, i.e. using the conventional `y * width + x` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the `or` operator and bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `^`, `&=`, `|=` and `^=`) can be used on boolean types in Java:

```
boolean[] orSum = new boolean[bool2D[0].length];

for (int i = 0; i < orSum.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < bool2D.length; k++) {
        orSum[i] = orSum[i] | bool2D[k][i];
    }
}
```